# Converting TopoJSON data to GeoJSON using JavaScript in browser?

Tags: javascript, geojson, topojson

There are many articles about how convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON using JavaScript, but I could not find how to convert TopoJSON to GeoJSON in the browser.

**Response:**

Using http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js, TopoJSON API’s 
feature() method we can convert a high-level TopoJSON object back into a GeoJSON structure:

```
geojson = topojson.feature(topojson,topojson.objects[topologyKey]);
```

Comment: Which is the best article you could find? At what point did you get stuck?

Comment: I find the answer, thx very much, using the TopoJson: http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js, i can convert topoJson in GeoJson:

Comment: Using the TopoJSON API’s feature() method we can convert a high-level TopoJSON object back into a GeoJSON structure

Comment: http://st0ven.github.io/2016/03/09/Rendering-geological-data-with-javascript/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Please also consider [edit]ing your question to address @Mesa's comment. And if you found your own solution, you can post (and accept) it as an answer!

Comment: Please write your self-answer in the area reserved for answers and not inside the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The answer isn't quite correct as the 1st `topojson` in `geojson = topojson.feature(topojson, topojson.objects[topologyKey]);` is the function from `d3js.org/topojson...` while the 2nd and 3rd `topojson` is an object variable, e.g. one uploaded from `countries-110m.json`. Let's call such variable `topoJson` then the correct statement is:

```
geojson = topojson.feature(topoJson,topoJson.objects[topologyKey]);
```

There is a more recent version: `d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js` or if you prefer more readable JavaScript: "https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.js".

It may be also useful to note in

```
geojson = topojson.feature(topoJson,topoJson.objects[topologyKey]);
```

the `topologyKey` can be for instance `countries` or `land`; so if you are applying it to such topojson(s) like `countries-110m.json`, i.e.:

```
geojson = topojson.feature(topoJson,topoJson.objects.countries);
```

and

```
geojson = topojson.feature(topoJson,topoJson.objects.land);
```

And if you want the features of both, `countries` and `land`, then you can do:

```
countries = topojson.feature(topoJson, topoJson.objects.countries);
land = topojson.feature(topoJson, topoJson.objects.land);
geoJson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection', 
  features: countries.features.concat(land.features)
};
```

(This can be put on just 2 lines of code...)
(BTW using names like `topoJson` or `geojson` is a bit misleading - JSON is a text, while these variables are objects...)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for posting a refrence but its nice readme says

"
TopoJSON is an extension of GeoJSON that encodes topology. Rather than representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are stitched together from shared line segments called arcs. This technique is similar to Matt Bloch’s MapShaper and the Arc/Info Export format, .e00.
"

https://github.com/topojson/topojson

```
//<script src="topojson.js">

    geojson = topojson.feature(topoJson,topoJson.objects[topologyKey]);
```

check out some esample data

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.366d7085cbe4445a8840ed1add74d617&right=cloud.f540ef831c104257aded604da3df1363